# windows phone charting using XML File

Tags: xml, windows-phone

I want to create a chart using AmChart and parse data from Xml File . i excut this code but no chart i don't know where is my error

```
This is my xml file
<Results>

<Chart>
<ChartName>Ahmed</ChartName>
<Category>25</Category>
</Chart>
<Chart>
<ChartName>Test</ChartName>
<Category>25</Category>

</Chart>
<Chart>

<ChartName>PFE</ChartName>
<Category>50</Category>
</Chart>

 </Results>
```

and XAML code

```
  <amq:PieChart x:Name="Pie" Height="500" Width="400"  TitleMemberPath="{Binding           ChartName}"  ValueMemberPath="{Binding Category}">

        </amq:PieChart>
```

My code behind 
      public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
         {

```
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        XDocument data = XDocument.Load("Results.xml");

        var results = from query in data.Descendants("Chart")
                      select new ResultModel((string)query.Element("ChartName"),
                       (int)query.Element("Category"));

    }

}
public class Test {
    public string ChartName { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }

    public Test(string label, int category)
    { ChartName = label; Category = category; } 
}
```

}